# cucumber spec test fail rails application

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

Below error got while execute cucumber spec in rails 5 application

```
  ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError)
  @http://127.0.0.1:4000/:2:7
  @http://127.0.0.1:4000/:3:8
  ./features/support/lib/common_actions.rb:112:in `finished_all_ajax_requests?'
  ./features/support/lib/common_actions.rb:106:in `block in wait_for_ajax'
  ./features/support/lib/common_actions.rb:105:in `wait_for_ajax'
```

Added default_max_wait_time  as 5 sec.
Below versions for capybra and selenium driver
capybara (3.2.1)
selenium-webdriver (3.14)

Answer (score 0):

You have your own (or copied from somewhere) code in features/support/lib/common_actions.rb which is executing JS in the page to try and see when all ajax requests have been completed (assumed based on method name).  This code is likely accessing `jQuery.active` and checking if it's zero. This was never really a good idea, and instead page synchronization should just be handled by checking for things actually changing in the page.

Given that it's now 2023 I'm guessing you may have removed the usage of jQuery from your application (using `fetch`, modern JS functionality, etc instead) and therefore you should be updating your synchronization to not need things like `wait_for_ajax`.  If you have not removed jQuery then you have an error in some JS which is preventing jQuery from loading. Check your browser console and fix whatever JS errors are being thrown.